# How to make facetgrid of 100% stacked area plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Here is what I made with a very long code.

[image]

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=[7,2], sharex=True, sharey=True)

ddf_Pclass_Sex0 = pd.crosstab(titanic_df[titanic_df.Survived == 0].Pclass, titanic_df[titanic_df.Survived == 0].Sex)
ddf_Pclass_Sex0.divide(ddf_Pclass_Sex0.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot.area(stacked=True, ax=ax1, color=['#55A868', '#4C72B0'])
ax1.set_title('Survived = 0', fontsize=9.5)
ax1.legend('')
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_ylabel('Percent (%)')

ddf_Pclass_Sex1 = pd.crosstab(titanic_df[titanic_df.Survived == 1].Pclass, titanic_df[titanic_df.Survived == 1].Sex)
ddf_Pclass_Sex1.divide(ddf_Pclass_Sex1.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot.area(stacked=True, ax=ax2, color=['#55A868', '#4C72B0'])
ax2.set_title('Survived = 1', fontsize=9.5)
ax2.set_xlabel('')

leg = ax2.legend(fontsize='small', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
leg.set_title('Sex', prop={'size':'small'})

fig.suptitle('Sex Composition in Percentage by Ticket Class', fontsize=9.5, y=1.06)
fig.text(.5, -.05, 'Ticket Class', ha='center', fontsize=9.5)

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 4, 1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is the crosstab table in the code.

[image]

This is how it looks after division.

But I have to make them 2 times in my code because I need one plot for the Survived = 0 and one for Survived = 1.

---

**How to achive the same effect with a much shorter amount of code? I feel very stupid to make subplots, and plot and customize them one by one.**

Answer (score 0):

You can set axes as a list, use list comprehension to setup an array of ddf_Pclass_Sex, then loop over them (to reduce repeated calls to xlabel, xticks and set title). Otherwise I think you need to call everything else,

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=[7,2], sharex=True, sharey=True)
ddf_Pclass_Sex = [pd.crosstab(titanic_df[titanic_df.Survived == i].Pclass, 
                              titanic_df[titanic_df.Survived == i].Sex) for i in range(2)]

for i, d, axs in enumerate(zip(ddf_Pclass_Sex, axs)):
    d.divide(d.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot.area(stacked=True, 
                                              ax=ax, 
                                              color=['#55A868', '#4C72B0'])
    ax.set_title('Survived = ' + str(i), fontsize=9.5)
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 4, 1))

ax[0].set_ylabel('Percent (%)')
leg = axs[1].legend(fontsize='small', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
leg.set_title('Sex', prop={'size':'small'})
fig.suptitle('Sex Composition in Percentage by Ticket Class', 
             fontsize=9.5, y=1.06)
fig.text(.5, -.05, 'Ticket Class', ha='center', fontsize=9.5)
plt.show()
```

Sorry cannot run without the dataframes. In my experience, it's actually better to keep the code more like you had it before. Even if it is longer, it makes it much easier when you need to adjust later on; everything is explicit and can change things easily if you want differences in the two plots.